# concatenate syntax format

Tags: php, concatenation

I have this php echo statement for a checkbox that is in a loop:

```
echo "<input name='battery[$i]' type='checkbox' id='battery[$i]' value='Yes' style='margin-top:10px; margin-left:15px;' />";
```

I would like to add this condition to it based on a query result:

```
<?php if($rowbill['battery'] == "Yes") print "checked"; ?>
```

But I am having a hard time getting the correct syntax for the concatenate, please some help would be appreciated.

Comment: so like: echo "<input name='battery[$i]' type='checkbox' id='battery[$i]' " . ($rowbill['battery']=="yes" ? "checked" : "") . "value='Yes' style='margin-top:10px; margin-left:15px;' />";

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "<input name='battery[$i]'" .($rowbill['battery'] == "Yes" ? "checked='checked'" : ""). " type='checkbox' id='battery[$i]' value='Yes' style='margin-top:10px; margin-left:15px;' />";
```

Comment: no, change it to ("checked='checked'"":"")  Internet Explorer will check it once it finds checked=

Comment: @Shehabox: You are right, that is the better solution. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For readability, I prefer set before a var

```
$checked = $rowbill['battery'] == "Yes"? ' checked="checked"' : '';
```

and after:

```
echo "<input name='battery[$i]' type='checkbox' id='battery[$i]' value='Yes' style='margin-top:10px; margin-left:15px;'$checked />";
```

Otherwise, only in one

```
echo "<input name='battery[$i]' type='checkbox' id='battery[$i]' value='Yes' style='margin-top:10px; margin-left:15px;'".($rowbill['battery'] == "Yes"? ' checked="checked"' : '')." />";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 '<input name="'.battery[$i].'" type="checkbox" id="'.battery[$i].'" value="Yes" style="margin-top:10px; margin-left:15px;"'.($rowbill['battery'] == 'Yes' ? ' checked="checked"' : '').'>';
```

Note how using `''` delimiters makes it easier to concatenate when you need to use `""` as part of your output.

Comment: thank you for the tip. ill start using ' as my delimiter going forward as i do see how its easier to concatenate with it

Comment: I agree with @Boaz regarding the delimiters. But remember that this also means you have to concat if you want to use variables inside the string. Anyway, there might be a slight performance gain using `''` as well, because PHP doesn`t have to check for code inside the string.

Comment: More on this topic in [this nice post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php).